# Flutter Column with parent Animated height overflow problem

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble with a flutter animation I have made. I animate the height of a container to 0 and the content inside the container overflows.

```
//Parent 
Container(
            width: screenWidth,
            height: panelHeight // ----------------------------------> This is the height that changes
            child: Builder(builder: ((context) {
               // returns the code below 
               return DefaultTabControllerChild();
              }
            })),

// Child
DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Column( // ----------------------------------------> Error is here 
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 50,
              child: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "tab 1",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text(
                      "tab 2",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  // some children 
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

The main problem is the tabBarviews labels (tab 1 and tab 2) overflow when the panel height is animated too small. The error is at child: Column. 
If the app is exported in production mode then there is no problems but the yellow and black line in debug mode annoys me.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `Scaffold` widget a parent to your `Container` to get rid of the yellow and black lines.

> Instead of -

```
height: panelHeight,
```

> Try this -

```
height: panelHeight > TabBar(
tabs: <Widget>[
Tab(
text: 'Hi',
icon: Icon(Icons.camera_rear),)],).preferredSize.height?panelHeight: 48,
```

I added the icon just in case.